# Slice and get value from a list of array

Tags: python, numpy, slice

I have a list of array as:

```
a = [np.array([199, 299]), np.array([198, 298]), np.array([197, 297]), np.array([196, 296]), np.array([100, 210])]
```

How can I get back a new list like this from `a`:

```
result = [[199, 198, 197, 196, 100]
          [299, 298, 297, 296, 210]]
```

Comment: `np.column_stack(a)`?

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!

Comment: `np.transpose(a)`